# 質問一覧には、「最後の編集者」より「質問者」を表示して欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求

## 今の仕様

質問の一覧には、質問者でなく最後の編集者が表示されています。
したがって、下図のようにほとんどの質問に、[cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)さんのような「編集王」の名前が表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 問題

質問した人の名前や信頼度を見て、質問の詳細を見る価値があるかどうか（回答する価値があるかどうか）を判断したいときがあります。
しかし、今の仕様だと、このような判断ができません。

## 機能の提案

質問の一覧には、「最後の編集者」よりは「質問者」を表示した方が良いと思います。
質問者と編集者を両方表示するのもアリだと思いますが、スペース的には難しそうです。

Comment: ちなみに「回答する価値があるかどうか判断したい」と思われている理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: 「回答する価値」は言い過ぎました。
「この人の質問なら面白そう、難しいかもしれない、初歩的かもしれない」などの事前知識があるので、それを有効活用したかっただけです。
「この人の質問は、回答する/回答しない」のような意図はありません。

Comment: 両方表示することに賛成です。アクティブタブという文脈で質問の一覧性を高めるにあたって、「最後に誰が何を行ったか」が記載されることは、質問者名と比べても依然として重要な情報だと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSE でも同様の提案が11年前に出されており、小さな改善を経て現在に至っているようです。
(元々は一覧に名前とタイムスタンプしか表示されなかったが、質問、回答、編集の見分けがつくようになった)

[Active Question lists - Name should reflect original poster (and editor if exists)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65179)

他の回答やコメントでも言及されていますが、「質問の一覧」は複数の選択肢が用意されており、トップページ (=アクティブ) はその一つに過ぎないので、現状だと "自分の使い方に合うものを選んでね" となりそうです。

また、併記の案もありますが、一覧ページで実施すると情報過多になりそうなのと、質問ページでの併記も慣れてないユーザーにとっては誤解を招いているケースが稀にあります。

Answer (score 6):

ちなみに「ホーム」とか「スタック・オーバーフロー」のバナーではなく、地球儀？アイコン付きの「質問」の欄をクリックして「新着」でソートすれば質問者名で表示されます。
[image: 質問欄表示]

Answer (score 2):

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ トップのページに表示されているのは最近の更新時間順の一覧であり質問時間順の一覧ではないため、更新者の情報が表示されているのは妥当かなと考えています。連続で更新されている内容の検知に使っている側面もあるため、あまり削除されたくは無いです。

既に触れられているように更新者とは別に質問者の情報も併記するのもアリだとは思いますが、レスポンシブデザインまで考えると幅が問題そうですね。やるなら質問個別のページにあるように横に並べる形でしょうか↓

[image]